# Install apache,php and mysql on CentOS VPS

Tags: centos, php, apache-httpd

I try to install apache,php and mysql server by these commands.

```
yum install httpd
yum install php
install mysql-server mysql
service httpd start
service mysqld start to start your mysql server
```

after that,they were install completely,because I can make php file and run it by

```
php test.php
```

command.
now I want to see this page with out ssh and in my browser,I type my VPS ip address in browser but it doesn't response to me.

test.php file is in var/www folder with 777 permission.

Comment: It shoud be under /var/www/html directory

Comment: Does it just time out? Or are you getting an error such as file not found / forbidden? This could be a problem in many places. Start by checking your document root is in fact /var/www/ in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check apache (httpd) configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. For example, it maybe like this (my apache configuration on Debian):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName your-server-hostname
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```